# Creating a word-translator application in Python 3. Any "Best practices"?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code that translates English into the Chef's(from the muppet show) language

it should change these letters/sounds into the other language

```
Input   Output
tion    shun
an  un
th  z
v   f
w   v
c   k
o   oo
i   ee
```

I have to write a function (def) that converts it so that it will print the new language

```
print(eng2chef('this is a chicken'))
```

should return

```
zees ees a kheekken
```

my code so far is:

```
help_dict = { 
    'tion': 'shun', 
    'an': 'un', 
    'th': 'z',
    'v': 'f', 
    'w': 'v', 
    'c': 'k', 
    'o': 'oo', 
    'i': 'ee', 
} 
def eng2chef(s):

  s.split()
  for i in s:
    if i in help_dict:
      i = help_dict[i]
      print(i)

eng2chef('this is a chicken')
```

but this only changes certain letters and then prints those letters

```
ee
ee
k
ee
k
```

Can someone please Help!!

Comment: Hey, buddy! 
Check out the *static* `maketrans()` and the `translate()` methods in Python's string (str) class. 
It's a bit more hairy now than it was in Python 2, because of Unicode, but it would be both a good exercise and probably the most correct way to solve your problem!    I was half way finished with a proper answer and example, but my time ran out... Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by iteratively replace strings:

```
help_dict = [
    ('tion', 'shun'),
    ('an', 'un'),
    ('th', 'z'),
    ('v', 'f'),
    ('w', 'v'),
    ('c', 'k'),
    ('o', 'oo'),
    ('i', 'ee')
]
def eng2chef(s):
     for x, y in help_dict:
         s = s.replace(x,y)
     return s
```

But note that I changed your dict into a list so that the replacement order is enforced. This is critical because you do not want to replace 'w' into 'v' then replace 'v' into 'f', only the other way round.

Comment: Using `str.translate()` is faster than a loop-based solution using replace, plus the iterations causes space complexity increase. Try timing this using, say just 1000 words or more and compare that to using the `translate()`method. Bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your code splits each character making it to target only single letters and change them.

```
help_dict = { 
    'tion': 'shun', 
    'an': 'un', 
    'th': 'z',
    'v': 'f', 
    'w': 'v', 
    'c': 'k', 
    'o': 'oo', 
    'i': 'ee', 
} 
def eng2chef(word):
    new_word = word
    for key in help_dict.keys():
        new_word = word.replace(key, help[key])
    print(new_word)
eng2chef('this is a chicken')
```

Output : zees ees a kheeken

This targets all the words in the passed in input that are found in the dictionary, replacing them with values given.
I hope this helps.